# JQuery response is null but actual response is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using JQuery to make an Ajax call. I used a sniffer to catch the response text:

```
{"error_code":0,"message":"SUCCESS","data":{"session_token":"3efd9dde-a839-4e91-9415-4c2f6cba5b7b"}}
```

But the response returned on the success callback is null. Anyone got any ideas? (see jquery code below.

Jquery code:

```
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://184.72.58.99/matchaapi/API/User/Login",
   data: { email: emailval, password: pwordval, developer_key: devkey },
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                           xhr.setRequestHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8" );
                       },
   success: function(resp) {
      alert(resp);
      $("#status p").html(resp.message);
     }});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess... is your site being served from the same site as the API you are trying to call? You can't make an AJAX request to another server directly from the browser unless you use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) (see [jsonp parameter in jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). If the API doesn't support it then you will need to proxy the calls through your web server.

Comment: yup. that was it. completely forgot about this. thanks so much!

Comment: Great. Can you do me a favor hit the green "accept" checkmark next to the answer? Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

What version of jQuery, and what browser? Try binding to the `complete` event rather than the `success` event.

Comment: +1 - If I remember correctly, `complete` returns a response, whereas `success` doesn't.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies:
firefox 3.6.2 and safari 4.0.4
jquery 1.4.2

complete only returns the text status and request object, not the response. (i tried it.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery API [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The [success] function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the
>   server, formatted according to the
>   'dataType' parameter

Maybe the data isn't formatted as proper JSON?